# What is a .CDB database file? And how can I read it using C#?

Tags: .net, database

My current mission is to read a .CDB database and dump information from it. My first problem is that.. I don't know what a .CDB database file is. Second, I don't know how to open it as I don't know this extension (*incredibly I couldn't find any info on Google*). Lastly, I need to code a C# program to read it.

As I don't think there's a driver for this possibly forsaken extension, maybe the solution is to convert it to a more common format before reading it through my own sofware.

Any tips would be apprecitated

Comment: That's not a filename extension in common use by mainstream dbase engines.  Send it back.

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html). Down the page you'll find several implementations how to work with the database. There are .Net version of [Python](http://ironpython.net/) and [Ruby](http://ironruby.net/) you might use to convert the database to a more conventional format.